# Overflow problems in IE7 and older

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, overflow

Just released a website - [www.jabsy.com](http://www.jabsy.com)

Figured it's easier if you just go there and test this out yourself instead of me explaining exactly what's happening. Go there in IE7 or older, OR in IE8/9 and set compatibility mode to IE7 standards (or older), and you'll see the two sort drop-downs (which are really just styled lists), and the Facebook button drop down INTO the message container `div`.

Not only that, but if you switch to "Worldwide" and "Live", as the messages are flowing into the container, they then come out the bottom and you can still see them (even though `overflow` is set to `hidden`).

I don't know if both of these issues are related or not. Do you guys mind taking a look and telling me what this could be? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remove `position; absolute` from your `#filters` div and also remove `margin-top: 34px` from the `#posts` div this should bring it into line across browser

there shouldn't be any need to remove the `#filters` div from the flow  (what the absolute positioning is doing) as you can control any spacing required with a positive or negative top margin on `#posts`

This removes the quirky IE positioning problem, which is what this is ;)

Comment: This actually does work great to bring everything back into line. However, there are two issues with this. 1) After making these changes, when you mouse-over the filters, they appear like half behind the posts, and when you move the mouse to make a selection, they disappear making it impossible to click one. 2) The issue where the posts div overflow:hidden; for it's elements is still there, they still come out the bottom when they don't fit. Is this something I'm going to have to live with?

Comment: working blind now as I am not replicating the dropdown problem - but for the not being able to select menu/filters.. add `position: relative;` and `z-index: 1;` to `#filters` to try to bring the menus over the messages div - BUT I am not getting messages so am not seeing the `overflow: hidden;` (or not hidden ;)) problem,

Comment: If you switch to live, and switch the radius to worldwide, you should get messages :) but thanks I'll try that for the other problem. Thanks again for sticking with this!

Comment: I've tried live and the worldwide radius.. nothing is coming up (both FF and IE), apart from the the "no messages" mesage - I also  tried posting a jab and nothing :(

Comment: Hmm, well that might be a different issue, lol. Is it finding your location? (Did it ask if it could use yours?)

Comment: I could always just call hide(); within JQuery as an element comes out of the container, that wouldn't be a HUGE deal. However, I'm still confused to why you can't see messages, as that means the site isn't working for some reason, haha.

Comment: yes it asked and I allowed.. funny thing it asked me every time I refreshed the page, I tried the 2 browsers as well in case it was a FF add-on, but nada.. sorry - `overflow: hidden` should do it and I'm stumped as to why not, jQuery `hide()` would just hide the whole div wouldn't it?

Comment: @slandau let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1163/discussion-between-clairesuzy-and-slandau)

Comment: ill try and hide each message div (that u cant see)